# Turtlebot Spinning

Tags: ros, turtlebot-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having an issue when simulating a turtlebot in gazebo where the turtlebot will spin around while being given velocity commands. I've had this issue both when following this tutuorial: http://learn.turtlebot.com/2015/02/03/9/ , and when writing scripts to give velocity commands myself. The turtlebot can eventually navigate to its target location, it just spins on the way and sometimes will spin so much that it falls over.  This isn't an issue when using teleop commands.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239340/turtlebot-spinning/) by [newellr](https://answers.ros.org/users/27470/newellr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-07-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've found that turtlebot_navigation requires a bit of tuning. It's not bad if the (simulated) turtlebot is already facing in the general direction of a nav goal, but if the little guy has to do a 180, it's Spin City (extreme overshoot when coming about). Here are the settings I use (from my launch file):

```
  <!-- move_base -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml"/>
  <!-- default turtlebot is poorly-tuned-->
  <param name="move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_rot_vel" value="1.0"/>
  <param name="move_base/DWAPlannerROS/acc_lim_theta" value="10.0"/>
```

This (mostly) damps the overshoot in my setup.

---

Originally posted by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) with karma: 567 on 2016-09-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Stopfer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4049/stopfer/) on 2016-10-07**:
Thanks, that fixed the problem for me. The question is, whether this is a problem.

- If move_base is poorly tuned for
  gazebo simulation, is it good tuned
  for the real robot?
- If it is good tuned for the real
  robot, is gazebo bad simulating the
  real robot?

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2016-10-07**:\

> is gazebo bad simulating the real robot?

Good question. Unfortunately, I don't own a Turtlebot (would love to have one, though).

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2016-10-07**:
Oh, BTW, would you mind marking the answer as correct if it did the trick?

**Comment by [Stopfer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4049/stopfer/) on 2016-10-08**:
That can only be done by the original poster.

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2016-10-08**:
Ah, missed that.